# Forwarding from domain names without using frames

Tags: html, url, dns, forwarding

I own a domain name e.g. www.mydomain.com

I also own a web server e.g. www.myserver.com

After navigating to my web server via www.myserver.com clicking on links to different pages within my servers file structure will result in a change in URL...

For example

Clicking on a link to main.html will result in www.myserver.com/main.html

However if I use framed forwarding from my domain name www.mydomain.com and perform the same action the url will not change since only the internal frame containing myserver's content will be changed...

this I know is a fundemental problem with using frames, however there must be some way of maintianing a full url with the domain name i.e.

www.mydomain.com/main.html

I have managed to achieve this with frames by making the links use

href="www.mydomain.com/main.html"

instead of

href="main.html"

But this seems to be a bit of a dirty method in my opinion. Any ideas?

This is probably a very stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Why use "framed forwarding"  It would seem what you are really wanting is the content / data from www.mywebserver.com  to show up under www.mydomainname.com .

Simply add the domain to your webserver's configuration and let it serve the content. No frames necessary.

Comment: hi there, how would i configure my server inorder to do so? I am using IIS7 to manage the server